# Find pattern in time series graph with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I would like to find a pattern in a pandas data frame.The real problem looks like this picture:

[I would like to find the blue pattern in the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvOQQ.jpg)

My idea was:

1. Make a pattern model of what I'm looking for
2. Compare the pattern with the data frame and calculate euclidean distances pairwise between data frame and pattern
3. Move the pattern along the graph step by step and calculate euclidean distance for every point
4. Plot all euclidean distances
5. Where the euclidean distances are minimal are the pattern locations

here is my code (I make an example df just to try something out. The original df is too big):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

d = {'Time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22], 
'Value': [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d2 = {'Time': [0, 1, 2] , 'Value': [1, 2, 3]}
patch = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

def orig(df, patch):

df['corr'] = np.nan

for i in range(df.shape[0]):

    #select the df window with the same size of patch
    window = df[i : i+patch.shape[0]]

    #If window and patch have different shapes --> Break
    if window.shape[0] != patch.shape[0] :

        break

    else:
        patch.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)          
        window.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

        df['corr'] = cdist(df[['Value']], patch[['Value']],'euclidean')

return df
```

Unfortunately it is not working properly. To calculate euclidean distances cdist needs at least 2 dimensions, but I would like to considerate only the difference between pattern (patch) and the actual df. If I create another column only with 1 just for the code to work I get wrong results as well.
 Anyone could give me a hint about how to identify a pattern from one data frame in the other? Maybe I am trying the harder way.

Comment: I can't see where you initiate your dataframe.
`df = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]` is a list not a dataframe

Comment: Hi, you are right. It's just a list to simulate a df. I will change it

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for pointing it. Now I updated the problem. I hope that it is clearer. I don't want to update the original df because it is huge. But now it should looks closer to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed your dataframe creation, also function definition, but not sure about the output if it's what you are expecting:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

d = {'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], 
'col2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d2 = {'col1': [0, 1, 2] , 'col2': [1, 2, 3]}
patch = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

def orig(df, patch):

    df['corr'] = np.nan

    for i in range(df.shape[0]):

        #select the df window with the same size of patch
        window = df[i : i+patch.shape[0]]

        #If window and patch have different shapes --> Break
        if window.shape[0] != patch.shape[0] :

            break

        else:
            patch.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)          
            window.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

            df['corr'] = cdist(df[['col2']], patch[['col2']],'euclidean')

    return df

orig(df, patch)
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks for fixing my df, that's very nice from you. My desired output is in which positions of df the pattern (1, 2, 3) can be found or at least how similar is the graph (1, 2, 3) compared to my df in different positions. Is the question clear? I added a picture in my original question for a better problem understanding